# How to check if 2 network interfaces can communicate

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I want to be able to tell programatically if 2 network interfaces (lets say eth0 and wlan0) are  on either the same network, or in some network architecture that allows one to reach the other (such as one router being a client of another router). I would have hoped to be able to do

```
ping -I wlan0 <eth0 ip>
```

but while this worked for other ip addresses on the network eth0 is on, it did not work for the actual address of my device.
I also tried a similar idea by hitting a local web server:

```
curl -i wlan0 <eth0 ip>:<server port>
```

but this appears to just always work because it is routed locally.
Is there something that can be done to the routing table to force the `curl` command to got out over the network? Or maybe a different approach entirely? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is very OS-specific, so you should add a proper OS tag. For example if it's Linux, you have to state the linux tag or a linux-related tag.

Comment: I'm not 100% positive, but I think the solution may involve sending a broadcast packet out one interface and watch for it to arrive on the other. This may involve writing some code in your language of choice.